# How would one remove yellow eyes instead of red eyes?

Tags: flash, post-processing, red-eye

On a recent trip to Madagascar, we were able to capture some interesting animals during the night, where of course we used flash. The following photo is not made by me...

http://www.flickr.com/photos/31109147@N00/2743758622

...but we have many with the same problem as in that photo: yellow eyes. Applying standard red eye post processing on it results in light grey, which looks equally unnatural as yellow.

I was wondering if anybody knows of an easy way to post process this into a natural look, other than of course manual painting, which is a painful exercise. One thing I have tried so far is selective color replacement, but that still is a very diligent process

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in Photoshop cs6:

Make a hue sat layer with a mask of the eyes on it.  in the yellow channel try lowering the saturation and brightness.  Maybe even pushing the yellow into a more neutral color

Comment: Thank you, although that does look like selective color replacement, it seems to work better compared to how I do such a thing in LR.

Comment: No problem, is the goal to make that bright yellow almond a dark brown or black color?

Comment: Yes, the goal would be to make it black, but not 100% black.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a program like [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) or Photoshop to *burn* into the Y channel in the eye area.

On GIMP's page, there's an [old tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Red_Eye_Removal/) that sort of follows the process.
However, instead of using the Channels directly, you should Decompose the image (*[Colors]->[Components]->[Decompose]->"CMYK"*) and work on the resulting *yellow-k* layer.
When you're done, just Recompose.

Photoshop's menus vary, but it must have something very similar.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm a PS user, I highly appreciate your answer.

Comment: A PS workflow should be very similar (if not identical). Do let us know what worked best for you.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OSX fans, [GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/download/) has a RedEyeRemoval tool.  You can configure the tool to be essentially an "AnyUglyColorEyeRemoval" tool by eyedrop-sampling the retina color in your photo and feeding that to the removal algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Photoshop to zoom in on the eyes, select the areas of the eyes that you want to remove the yellow from...after making your selection, go to "hue/saturation", choose yellow, and bring down saturation to get the yellow out.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.paintshoppro.com/en/pages/red-eye/
Here is a tool in PaintShop Pro that fixes red eyes but it also applies to your problem with yellow eyes as well as animal eyes, this can fix your problem :) Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Photography! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.